# React - Using state in component by useContext

Tags: reactjs

Hello I got stuck during creating app using hooks
I do not why but my Component does not download a state from my Context Component or maybe my initial state does not update correctly. Does somebody have any idea what's going on?

Context Component:

```html
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const WeatherDataContext = createContext();

const WeatherDataContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState(
        {
            city: null,
            temp: null
        }
    )
    const addWeather = (city, temp) => {
        setWeather({
            city,
            temp
        })
    }
    
    return (
        <WeatherDataContext.Provider value={{weather, addWeather}}>
            {props.children}
        </WeatherDataContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default WeatherDataContextProvider
```

Form - axios - Component:

```html
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import { WeatherDataContext } from '../context/WeatherDataContext';
import axios from 'axios'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


const WeatherForm = () => {
    const {addWeather} = useContext(WeatherDataContext);
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${value}&appid=${KEY}&units=metric`)
            .then(res => {
                
                
               addWeather(res.data.name, res.data.main.temp)
                
            })
      
    }

    return (
        <div class='weather-form'>
            <form onSubmit={handleChange}>
                <input placeholder='City' onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} value={value} required/>
                <Link to='/weather'><button>Search</button></Link>
                
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default WeatherForm
```

And final component where I want to use my update state

```html
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import { WeatherDataContext } from '../context/WeatherDataContext';

const WeatherFront = () => {
    const {weather} = useContext(WeatherDataContext)
    
    console.log(weather)
    return (
        <div class='weather-front'>
            <h1>City: {weather.city}, Temperatura: {weather.temp}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default WeatherFront
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is not submitting the form - it navigates away from the page instead.
So `handleChange` is not being called.

You can call it from buttons `onClick` instead of forms `onSubmit`. Be sure to omit `e.preventDefault()` then, so that parent Link can still navigate.

```
const WeatherForm = () => {
  const { addWeather } = useContext(WeatherDataContext)
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${value}&appid=${KEY}&units=metric`)
            .then(res => {
                
                
               addWeather(res.data.name, res.data.main.temp)
                
            })
  }

  return (
    <div class="weather-form">
      <form >
        <input
          placeholder="City"
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          value={value}
          required
        />
        <Link to="/weather">
          <button onClick={handleChange}>Search</button>
        </Link>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Be sure to wrap both pages inside the same context:

```
<WeatherDataContextProvider>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/weather">
              <WeatherFront></WeatherFront>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <WeatherForm></WeatherForm>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
</WeatherDataContextProvider>
```

Comment: I change the button to '<input
            type='submit'
            onClick={handleChange}
            />'

Comment: And I still dont have update data from my Context in WeatherFront component

Comment: When i submit my form and my app moves me to WeatherFront Component I still dont have my data and in console i get this:

Comment: index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in WeatherDataContextProvider (at WeatherSearch.js:10)
    in div (at WeatherSearch.js:9)
    in WeatherSearch (created by Context.Consumer)

Comment: Either use onSubmit on form (and then both `<button>` and `<input type="submit">` would be fine) but without Link, or you use onClick on a button inside a Link, not both. Form submit is not very useful mechanism if submit button is navigating away.

Comment: The warning sounds like you didn't wrap both WeatherForm and WeatherFront inside the (same) WeatherDataContextProvider. I'll update the answer to include example of how that would look.